# Transformar hexcode "&#x2b;" em "+" no JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

Estou utilizando uma API de pagamentos que exige que os números de telefone informados sejam no padrão E.164 (`+[Código do país][código da cidade][numero de 8~9 dígitos]`) e como string (como no exemplo abaixo).

Porém, ao adicionar o sinal de `+`, ele é transformado em `&#x2b;`. Tem alguma forma de transformar este código para `+` de novo?

```
{
    "object": "customer",
    "id": 233406,
    "external_id": "#123456789",
    "type": "individual",
    "country": "br",
    "document_number": null,
    "document_type": "cpf",
    "name": "João das Neves",
    "email": "joaoneves@norte.com",
    "phone_numbers": [
        "+5511999999999",
        "+5511888888888"
    ],
    "born_at": null,
    "birthday": "1985-01-01",
    "gender": null,
    "date_created": "2017-08-14T23:28:36.296Z",
    "documents": [
        {
            "object": "document",
            "id": "doc_cj6csivuv05zj696dkzzjbfmq",
            "type": "cpf",
            "number": "11111111111"
        }
    ],
    "addresses": [],
    "phones": []
}
```

Comment: Aonde que ele é transformado? Traga-nos mais informações

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente

```js
function htmlDecode(input) {
  var e = document.createElement('div');
  e.innerHTML = input;
  return e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}

console.log(htmlDecode("&#x2b;"));
```

A lib  `he` (para “entidades HTML”) é um codificador/decodificador de entidade `HTML` robusto escrito em JavaScript. Projeto [Aqui](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he)